# Generate a column with value 1 if first parent_id level > 1 than id level

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I want to get all the data from the table, and generate on the fly a column with the value 1 at the parent of the entries with this parent_id. And it should be compatible with "sql server", "postgres", "mysql".

```
id,parent_id,lft,rgt,level,title,alias,access,path,checked_out
1  0         0   7   0     root   root   0    root ...
2  1         1   2   1     ...
```

**Result should be:**

```
id,parent_id,lft,rgt,level,**button**,title,alias,access,path,checked_out
1  0         0   7   0        1       root   root   0    root  0...
2  1         1   2   1        **0**       ...
```

Is this ever possible, I´ll never done such a complicated query before.

It should select all table entries, generate a new button column with value 1 or 0, and this only at the parent level of it's entries

Something like this but with a result of all entries:

```
SELECT a.id,b.id,a.level,a.level+1 as button
FROM `categories` a
JOIN `categories` b ON a.id=b.parent_id
WHERE a.id < b.id AND a.level+1 = b.level AND b.id-a.id=1;
```

Comment: This will be quite easy using Postgres and SQL Server, but really hard with MySQL due to it's lack of modern SQL features.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name While I agree, it's amazing how much of the modern SQL features MySQL users can emulate/fake using query variables. Sometimes really wish we had those in PostgreSQL.

Comment: *Why* do you need this to work in all of these RDBMS? Trying to stay "db-agnostic" is a big pain and very error prone.

Comment: It has to work at a cms

Comment: @ChrisGitare then the CMS needs to support dynamic query dispatch, where it can have queries where there's a generic query, and then overrides for different DBs that're used instead if provided. So you can write the "SQL Standard(ish)" query (often works for PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server), the "funky Oracle query", and the "MySQL procedure query". Attempting to write logic-heavy queries that are DB-agnostic is doomed to painful failure, sadly.

Comment: Yea, I guess Joomla3.3 has a dynamic query dispatch for this three RDBMS. My problem for now is to implement one query to get all table results and create on the fly a column as an anker for a button for all categories that have any children. I want avoid two queries to do something similar.

Comment: @ChrisGitare: I added all conditions from your question to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` and `EXISTS` should work in all of these RDBMS:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, lft, rgt, level
     , CASE WHEN EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 FROM tbl AS b
          WHERE  b.parent_id = a.id
          AND    b.level = a.level + 1
          -- AND    b.id > a.id   -- this one is redundant
          AND    b.id = a.id + 1)
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS button
     , ...
FROM   tbl AS a;
```

This returns rows that have *any* children with `button = 1`. Else `button = 0`.